# AutoCompleteTextView Adapter not dropdown onTextChange?

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-arrayadapter

I'm working on `AutoCompleteTextView`. Adapter is not populating any data according to my `OnTextChangeListener`, it is as it is at first time at time of initialization.

```
  public void fn_LoadLrnoDetail(ArrayList<String> lst_Name) {
    try {
        progressBar.showDialog();
        Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, new ArrayList<String>());

        autotxtLrno.setAdapter(Adapter);

        if (lst_Name != null && lst_Name.size() > 0) {
            Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, lst_Name);
            autotxtLrno.setAdapter(Adapter);
            Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        progressBar.hideDialog();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "fn_LoadLrnoDetail: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

This is my Method for `AutoCompleteTextView`. The problem is whatever data is in first time, it remains same even data is change according to `OnTextChangeListener`.

```
    autotxtLrno.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            halfClear();
            custom_list.clear();
            Log.e(TAG, "onTextChanged: " + lst_Name.size() + "  " + lst_Name);
            for (String custom : lst_Name) {
                if (custom.contains(autotxtLrno.getText().toString())) {
                    custom_list.add(custom);
                }

            }
            Log.e(TAG, "custom: " + custom_list + "  " + custom_list.size());
            if (custom_list.size() > 0) {
                fn_LoadLrnoDetail(custom_list);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

This is the method for `OnTextChangedListener`. If I changed the text nothing is populating. 
Can you please tell me where i'm making the mistake.

**Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks in advance**

Comment: your data comes from sqlite database, right? so use `SimpleCursorAdapter` and setup its `FilterQueryProvider`: it will take maybe 10 lines of code, thats all, no need for any `TextWatcher`

Comment: yes. My data is from `SQLite`, any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: i already told you: use `SimpleCursorAdapter` and setup its `FilterQueryProvider`, all you need to do is to return a `Cursor` from `runQuery` method: max 10 lines of code

Comment: and if you want it to be even shorter then 10 lines of code override `runQueryOnBackgroundThread()` in your custom `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: Still can't able to achieve this

Comment: I'll check this and let yu know

Comment: Actually I need to learn abt that then only I can apply. I don't know how to use this

Comment: That I need to learn

Comment: there is nothing to learn: simply read `SimpleCursorAdapter` documentation, it is just couple of paragraphs

Comment: can you please refer some eg? @pskink

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html, it says how to deal with filtering in `AutoCompleteTextView` and if you use `FilterQueryProvider` your code will have 10 lines but if you do that smart way by extending `SCA` and overriding `runQueryOnBackgroundThread` all will be done just in 7 lines of code

Comment: thanks a lot psking, i'll let you when i'll try this, and i'll accept the answer once you write same in answer box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131467/discussion-between-aman-singh-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is whatever data is in first time, it remains same even
>   data is change according to OnTextChangeListener

**Solution** :

You are creating the new adapter every time when the data changes.

```
          if (lst_Name != null && lst_Name.size() > 0) {

This line-->   Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, lst_Name);
             autotxtLrno.setAdapter(Adapter);
             Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Instead move your adpater initialize to oncreate method clear and set the adapter to the listView  and call
`notifyDataSetChanged` method like this

```
Adapter.clear();
Adapter.add(lst_name)
autotxtLrno.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

Comment: but its populating the data whatever i put at time of initialization

Comment: no, still same problem. filter is not getting applied

Comment: even i tried to change adapter in `onTextChanged` also but no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131407/discussion-between-aman-singh-and-user01232).